# how to close db connections in except clause

Tags: python

originally, I didn't have a main() function. I just had a whole bunch of code in:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I'm trying to refactor the code a bit so that it's a little cleaner and does come clean up in case the code raises an exception. So, now my code looks like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except :
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        engine.close()
        db.close()
```

the problem is, engine and db are both created inside of main(), so I don't really have a reference to them. Is there a way to handle the exception in this way, or do I have to make it more granular within the main() function?

edit: 
[very helpful article about with statements](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either the [`with` statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) with an appropriate context manager or [`try` ... `finally`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) to make sure that your connections are closed.

Comment: very foggy on 'with' after looking at a couple of sources. could you show an example?

Comment: `with open('somefile.ext', 'wb') as fp:` `fp.write('foo')`

Answer (score 3):

Put your exception handling inside `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers really are much better, but you **can** also pass data inside Exception objects if you raise them yourself or catch them, modify them, and re-raise them.

It's a much better practice to catch and handle your exceptions so that exceptions coming out of `main` are truly exceptional.